# Placement of この in the given sentence

Tags: translation, nuances

I have a doubt regarding the placement of この in the following sentence:

> ポケモンが住んでいるこのジャングルでは、あちこちでポケモンを見かけることができ、今も男たちの頭上で、マンキーの群れが木々の間を飛び移っていく。

The sentence is quite big and I only placed it for context. For the purpose of this question, the first part until ジャングルでは suffices.

So, I'd translate this as

> In this jungle where Pokemon live

In Japanese, however, I would have written

> このポケモンが住んでいるジャングルでは

Here's what I want to know:

1. Is my English translation correct?
2. If so, is my placement of この ungrammatical/unnatural, or can it appear in both ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your translation is correct.
2. You can put この in both places but they will have different meanings. In ポケモンが住んでいる**このジャングル** you are talking about '**this jungle** where pokemon live' i.e. a specific jungle.
   In **このポケモン**が住んでいるジャングル you are talking about 'a jungle where **this pokemon** lives' i.e. a specific pokemon.

I'm not sure if この can bind to ジャングル grammatically if ポケモンが住んでいる is in the middle, but even if it can it would not be the obvious translation.

Comment: "if この can bind to ジャングル grammatically if ポケモンが住んでいる is in the middle": It can, but ambiguous and not recommended, as you said.